# Why does the machine give the number of Terry Easton?

Tags: plot-explanation, person-of-interest

In Season 5 Episode 9 of *Person of Interest*, Reese was following Terry Easton, a locksmith, as he had received his number.

He finds him with an active bomb and takes him to the precinct. At the same time, Amir was captured and was kept at the precinct.

Easton reveals that his wife has been kidnapped by the mastermind "Voice", at the same time a lot of bomb threats come in.

Later, it is revealed that this is all an elaborate plan to kill Amir as Terry Easton is actually "Voice".

But if Terry's life was never in danger, then why did the Machine send his number?

Answer (score 5):

> But if Terry's life was never in danger, then why did the Machine send his number??

### The Machine doesn't just send numbers of victims.

What the machine knew (or didn't) isn't clear but the Machine knew **something** was going to happen...it's up to the Machine Gang to figure out what.

> You are being watched. The government has a secret system, a machine that spies on you every hour of every day. I know because I built it. I designed the machine to detect acts of terror but it sees everything. Violent crimes involving ordinary people, people like you. Crimes the government considered "irrelevant." They wouldn't act, so I decided I would. But I needed a partner, someone with the skills to intervene. Hunted by the authorities, we work in secret. You'll never find us, but **victim or perpetrator**, if your number's up... we'll find *you*